# What is the meaning of 'Don't take for granted'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

At Oscars Leonardo Di'Caprio ended his speech by saying
"Lets do not take this planet for granted, I do not take tonight for granted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a commonly used idiom. To "*[take something for granted](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+for+granted)*" simply means:

> - To expect someone or something to be always available to serve in some way without thanks or recognition

or

> - to value someone or something too lightly.

Here, DiCaprio means to say that he isn't willing to assume that the golden moment when he won the Oscar is the happiest moment of his life and nothing can be better than that. He means that his win doesn't mean he's going over his head and he isn't declaring himself to be the best. Even though he won the award, he will not settle for this. He will keep doing his best and not slack in his exceptional work as an actor.